# How to manage session with routing

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

We are developing an e-commerce website

In that while entering to the home page

A pop-up should be appear like the following image ..
[image: From the three options we have to select any one then entire site the products should be displayed of that classificaton only]

now while clicking any one button the page to be redirected to home page and the user can view the products according to that classification only and the pop up should not be displayed .. until the session continues.

the following is my html and j-query code for popup displaying

```
 <div class="row pop-up">
<div class="box small-6 large-centered"> <a href="#" class="close-button">&#10006;</a>
 <h3 style="color:lightgreen;font-size: 35px">Choose Your Classification</h3>
 <br>.
<p> <button class="button" ><a href="/shop/classification/choosen?class=comfort" style="color:white;font-size:20px">Comfort</a></button>
<br>
```

Luxury
      
    Convenience

j-query code is

```
$(function() {
 $('.pop-up').hide();
 $('.pop-up').fadeIn(1000);

  $('.close-button').click(function (e) { 

  $('.pop-up').fadeOut(700);
  $('#overlay').removeClass('blur-in');
  $('#overlay').addClass('blur-out');
  e.stopPropagation();

});
```

now while clicking the button it is redirecting to home page but pop-up is not hiding

now routing code is

```
    router.get('/shop/classification/choosen',function(req,res){
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
var malllll= req.query.class;
req.session.class = req.query.class;
var jj=req.session.class;
console.log("8888888888888"+malllll)

console.log("edjkbwe"+jj)

    }) ;
```

now my query is that how that classification to be reflected in every routing code